# Is $D^2$ a homogenous space?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Here $D^2$ means a disk. I want to determine whether it is a homogenous space, but I have no idea how to do it. However, I have come up with some preliminary ideas that may help.
The boundary of $D^2$ , which is $S^1$, is a homogeneous space since we can put it on the complex plane. And I wonder if we can do the similar thing. Another idea is $D^2$ is homeomorphic to $S^2_+$, and there is a fact that $S^2$ is a homogeneous space, so is there any connection between?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$D^2$ is not homogenous. It is a manifold with boundary and it is a more general fact that a homeomorphism between manifolds with boundary has to map boundary to boundary. And so no manifold with nonempty boundary is homogenous.

This can be shown by first showing that the half space $$\mathbb{H}^n=\{(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n\ |\ x_1\geq 0\}$$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$, which can be done by comparing these spaces with a single point removed. For $\mathbb{H}^n$ if you remove a point with first coordinate $0$ it remains contractible, but $\mathbb{R}^n$ minus point is never contractible.

Then you compare neighbourhoods of points in $\partial M$, which contain homeomorphic copies of $\mathbb{H}^n$ (that's pretty much the definition of manifold boundary) with neighbourhoods of $M\backslash\partial M$, which contain homeomorphic copies of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 0):

$D^2$ is not a homogeneous space, for the following reason.

If $f : D^2 \to D^2$ is a homeomorphism, and if $f(x)=y$, then the map of topological pairs $f : (D^2,D^2-x) \to (D^2,D^2-y)$ is a homeomorphism in the category of pairs, and therefore the induced relative homology homomorphism $f_* : H_2(D^2,D^2-x) \to H_2(D^2,D^2-y)$ is an isomorphism.

However, if $x \in \partial D^2$ then $H_2(D^2,D^2-x) \approx 0$ whereas if $y \in \text{int}(D^2)$ then $H_2(D^2,D^2-y) \approx \mathbb Z$. Each of these isomorphisms is a standard exercise in algebraic topology, proved using the long exact sequence in relative homology, and coming down to the fact that if $x \in \partial D^2$ then $D^2-x$ is contractible hence $H_1(D^2-x) \approx 0$, whereas if $y \in \text{int}(D^2)$ then $D^2-y$ is homotopy equivalent to a circle hence $H_1(D^2-y) \approx \mathbb Z$.

A similar proof works to show that if $M$ is an $n$-dimensional manifold with boundary then: if $x \in \partial M$ then $H_{n}(M,M-x) \approx 0$; whereas if $x \in \text{int}(M)$ then $H_{n}(M,M-x) \approx \mathbb Z$. So if $\partial M \ne \emptyset$ then $M$ is not a homogeneous space. The proof in this case is a bit more complicated than in the $D^2$ case, because one must also insert an application of the excision theorem.